# C# Regex - Match beginning of string and allow 2 random characters at end

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to achieve finding singular and plural words count together inside big chunk of text. I got an idea to make it work with regex (not perfect, but in my case it is great).

I want to have regex, that can take piece of string let's say 'piece' and I want to get count of every existing word in that chunk of text that starts with 'piece' + can have 2 random characters at the end (maybe just some specific characters would be even better).

So inside this text "I had a piece of cake. There are many pieces left." I would give regex word 'piec' and it will return '2', because there are 2 words that starts with 'piec' and there are 2 random characters at the end. If in sentence would be word 'piecess' it wouldn't count it, because it have 3 random chars after base word 'piec'.

I explained it as well as I could :D I hope you will understand. I didn't find answer how to do 'can have 2 random characters at end'.

Can someone please help me? Thank you very much for all answers

Comment: You could use `\bpiec\w{0,2}\b` for your example. You might be better off looking into a library that can pluralize words (e.g., Humanizer) and then searching for the singular/plural.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Exactly what I need. Also thank you for tip, I will check Humanizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random character is defined with `[A-Za-z]`. If you would like to consider only lower case characters it would be `[a-z]`.

To define that it should have at at max two of those characters to add `{0,2}` to the end. Hence if we take your piece example it would be `piec[A-Za-z]{0,2}`. However to apply the regexp to a sentence you should also define that the word should be surrounded by non-character letters (`\W`) so we get `\Wpiec[A-Za-z]{0,2}\W`. However the word could be at the beginning (`^`) or the end (`$`) and then there would be no non-character letter and we get

`(\W|^)(RegE[A-Za-z]{0,2})(\W|$)`

Comment: Great and simple. Thank you very much. I learned something new

Comment: Hello, I encountered small problem which I do not understand.

I have this text "hboy hboys boys boy" this pattern "^boy[a-z]{0,2}"

Why it return count of 0? Why it doesnt select boy and boys? It should be in words 'words that starts with 'boy' and can have 2 random characters in range of [a-z] at the end

Comment: Remove the `^`. It means that the expression neens to be at the start of the string.

Comment: But then it also takes hboy and hboys. I want it to start with base word (boy)

Comment: Try `(\W|^)`: Either a non character letter or start of string in this case